# Why does my Cygwin copy or mkdir with a variable in directory name not work?

Tags: bash, variables, syntax, cygwin, cp

After building a Unity standalone build, I want to create some copies of both the executable and it's data folder, so I can run multiple instances of it. To do this easily, I've made this script:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
    do cp SomeProject.exe SomeProject$i.exe
    cp -r SomeProject_Data/ SomeProject$i_Data
    echo i=$i done
done
```

However, while the copying of the executable works file, this folder copying doesn't. Instead of copying the datafolder to `SomeProject1_Data`, `SomeProject2_Data`, etc. It copies the first one to `SomeProject` and the next one inside that (and the following just overwrites the second, it seems).

I've tried inserting a `mkdir SomeProject$i_Data` and copying "into" that, but this also just creates `SomeProject` in the first iteration, and following iterations complain that `SomeProject` already exists.

Any idea what's going on/wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just worked it out myself. I need {} around the i in the variable.
In my code `$i_Data` is seen as the variable name, which resolves to nothing/empty string. By adding {} around the `i`, it resolves correctly. So, working code is:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
    do cp SomeProject.exe SomeProject$i.exe
    cp -r SomeProject_Data/ SomeProject${i}_Data
    echo i=$i done
done
```

Comment: or double-quote as in my answer.

Comment: No, double quotes won't work. The problem is that it's seeing "i_Data" as the variable name, rather than just "i", so I need {} around. Will write a proper answer :)

Comment: Almost considering if I should delete the whole question... is it useful to anyone else, you think? :)

Comment: Might not. The system discourages me from doing so (and it is a valid question/answer, I guess)